# Screen mirroring using ChromeCast

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am building a screen mirroring app in android using media projection.
 Now, I want to mirror my mobile screen chromeCast enabled devices like **Vizio SmartCast Tv**, and other **chromeCast device**.
  Can I mirror my entire mobile screen using ChromeCast like Google Home App do.
 So, any kind of code example available that point me in the direction of screen mirroring using Google Cast SDK will be much appreciated.

Using Google Cast SDK, I only can cast Video using URL.
[I can Load this type of URL](https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4)